# How to execute an SOQL query written in Apex?

Tags: apex, soql, execute-anonymous

I'm trying to finish a challange of the [Write SOQL Queries](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_soql) Trailhead Unit. Problem description says:

> For this challenge, you will need to create a class that has a method
>   accepting two strings. The method searches for contacts that have a
>   last name matching the first string and a mailing postal code (API
>   name: MailingPostalCode) matching the second. It gets the ID and Name
>   of those contacts and returns them.

I created an Apex class:

```
public class ContactSearch {
    public static List<Contacts> searchForContacts(String lastname, String Postalcode){
        LastName=lastname;
        Mailingpostalcode=Postalcode;  
        List<Contacts> contacts[select ID,Name FORM contact WHERE LastName=:lastname AND Mailingpostalcode=:Postlecode];
        return Contacts;
    }
}
```

But I'm unable to write an anonymous apex script to execute this. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

The following code will solve your problem:

```
public class ContactSearch {
    public static List<Contact> searchForContacts(String lastName, String mailingPostalCode) {
        List<Contact> retList = [SELECT Id, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode
                                 FROM Contact
                                 WHERE LastName = :lastName AND MailingPostalCode = :mailingPostalCode];
        return retList;
    }   
}
```

Let's view it line-by-line:

```
public class ContactSearch
```

This is just a class definition. **Public** says that this class is in *public* scope

```
public static List<Contact> searchForContacts(String lastName, String mailingPostalCode)
```

This is method declaration. Again, **public** keyword makes this method public accessible(*public scope*).
**Static** means that this method is class-method(static-method) and not instance-method. Difference is that for instance-method you would omit **static** keyword, but you would need an instance of that class to call this method.
**`List<Contact>`** is return type of the method. It means that this method will return a `List` of `Contact` objects.
**searchForContacts** is method name, use it to call this method.
`String lastName, String mailingPostalCode` are parameters that are expected by this method.

```
List<Contact> retList = [SELECT Id, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode
                                 FROM Contact
                                 WHERE LastName = :lastName AND MailingPostalCode = :mailingPostalCode];
```

This line assigns the result of the query to **retList** variable.
`List<Contact> retList` makes a variable with name *retList* of type `List<Contact>`.
`SELECT Id, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode FROM Contact` is a simple query that will return all contacts. However, you only need the ones that match given parameters, so the next line of the query is:
`WHERE LastName = :lastName AND MailingPostalCode = :mailingPostalCode`
This adds a filter to the query, so that it will only return results which match **LastName** and **MailingPostalCode** with given parameters.

Note the `:` in the query before the parameters:

If you want to use variables in your query, they should have `:` in front. That tells your code that it's not the value to be searched for, but a variable from the code

`return retList;` will return the list of matching contacts that you just found

**update**: alternativly, instead of creating a retList variable, you could immediately return the query. Like this:

```
public class ContactSearch {
        public static List<Contact> searchForContacts(String lastName, String mailingPostalCode) {
            return [SELECT Id, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode
                                     FROM Contact
                                     WHERE LastName = :lastName AND MailingPostalCode = :mailingPostalCode];
        }   
    }
```

Comment: actually, instead of creating a *retList* variable, you could immediately return the query

Comment: mmmmh, you're giving the challenge answer ! thought that was forbidden here

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ContactSearch {
   public static List<Contact> searchForContacts(String lName,String pCode){
        return [SELECT ID,Name FROM Contact WHERE lastName =:lName AND MailingPostalCode =:pCode];
   }
}
```

You can validate this code by just clicking on the check button on your trilhead challenge page.

You can test this by writing following script in developer console anonymous block:

```
System.debug(ContactSearch.searchForContacts('testName','testCode'));
```

Let me know if you any problem in this.

Thanks